# Why Easyadmin is not considering constraint in a ManyToMany relation

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, easyadmin

I have a ManyToMany relation and if I try to delete one related item from MySQL I'm blocked with an error; instead if I try to delete the same item from Easyadmin i'm not blocked.

My expected behavior is to be blocked also by Easyadmin (v. 1.16 with Symfony v. 3.3.10). Please help...

These are my 2 entities:

**Lead:**

```
[...]

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LeadInterest", inversedBy="leads")
 * @JoinTable(name="leads_interests",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="lead_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"interestName": "ASC"})
 */
private $interests = null;

[...]

public function __construct() {
    $this->interests = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addInterest(LeadInterest $i) 
{
    if(!$this->interests->contains($i)) {
        $this->interests->add($i);
    }
}

public function removeInterest(LeadInterest $i)
{
    $this->interests->removeElement($i);
}

public function getInterests()
{
    return $this->interests;
}

[...]
```

**LeadInterest:**

```
[...]

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Lead", mappedBy="interests")
 */
private $leads;

[...]

public function __construct() {

    $this->leads = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->lastUpdate = new \DateTime();

}

public function addLead(Lead $lead)
{
    $this->leads[] = $lead;
    return $this;
}

public function removeLead(Lead $lead)
{
    $this->leads->removeElement($lead);
}

public function getLeads()
{
    return $this->leads;
}

[...]
```

This is the error when I try to delete une item from MySQL:

```
mysql> delete from leadInterest where id=6;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app`.`leads_interests`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2135A27B5A95FF89` FOREIGN KEY (`interest_id`) REFERENCES `leadInterest` (`id`))

mysql> delete from lead where id=88;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app`.`leads_interests`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2135A27B55458D` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_id`) REFERENCES `lead` (`id`))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why EasyAdmin isn't throwing any errors but you are clearly missing `onDelete="CASCADE"` telling MySQL to delete those foreing keys as well.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LeadInterest", inversedBy="leads")
 * @JoinTable(name="leads_interests",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="lead_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"interestName": "ASC"})
 */
```

Comment: Sorry Kiril but your answer doesn't solve my problem. I want to block the deletion of a Lead linked to one or more LeadInterests (and vice-versa)